# Sublime Text 3 and Rspec, building error

Tags: ruby, rspec, sublimetext, sublimetext3

I just have installed Sublime Text 3 and few packages with it.

I'm doing some Ruby stuff and currently want to build my program inside Sublime Text.

But when I hit Cmb + b in order to build it, I've got few errors in Sublime Text console :

```
> [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'rspec'
[cmd: ['rspec', '-I /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Dropbox/pragmatic-ruby', '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Dropbox/pragmatic-ruby/studio_game.rb']]
[dir: /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Dropbox/pragmatic-ruby]
[path: /usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin]
[Finished]
```

Sometimes I also get :

```
Could not find 'rspec-core' (>= 0) among 39 total gem(s) (Gem::LoadError)
```

Comment: What packages are you using?

Comment: ApplySyntax, CTags, Emmet, GitGutter, Hamlpy, RSpec, SASS, SublimeLint, Theme- Soda.

Comment: Sublime Text 3 is still in beta so this might be a bug. The other thing I have heard of is some packages use their own cmd + b switch but I am not sure the applies to he package you have. I use sublime text and rspec for all my ruby code but I use the command line to run spec tests so I am not sure I can be any further help.

Comment: I'm not doing any tests in my current program, that is just a simple Ruby script.

Comment: If you are not testing then why do you have rspec?

Comment: Because I do some testing in other program. I tried to uninstall the package and the gem, still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

It seems it can't find the `rspec` command. Try installing `rspec` from your terminal -

```
gem install rspec      # for rspec-core, rspec-expectations, rspec-mocks
gem install rspec-core # for rspec-core only
```

Comment: Already installed  : rspec (2.14.1)
rspec-core (2.14.7, 2.14.5)
rspec-expectations (2.14.3)
rspec-mocks (2.14.3)

Answer (score 0):

Rspec Package includes its own build system

```
{
    "cmd": ["rspec", "-I ${file_path}", "$file"],
    "file_regex": "# ([A-Za-z:0-9_./ ]+rb):([0-9]+)",
    "working_dir": "${project_path:${folder:${file_path}}}",
    "selector": "source.ruby",

    "windows":
    {
            "cmd": ["rspec.bat", "-I ${file_path}", "$file"]
    }
}
```

If your Tools->BuildSystem is set to automatic maybe try and just use Ruby. I am not exactly sure how BuildSystem

Comment: Where is this sublime-build file located? I would like to modify it slightly to fit my needs but have not been able to find it.

Comment: @itslittlejohn according to this http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/build you can access them from inside sublime text. But they are in the packages directory

Comment: I found that if I installed it via package control, the sublime-build file was not available, but if I installed it via a clone from github, it's just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Source: https://github.com/SublimeText/RSpec/issues/50#issuecomment-64077090

> Since the build command itself is just a configuration that is used by Sublime directly, I can't think of a way to dynamically do it.
>
> One easy way to work around it is to copy the [build file](https://github.com/SublimeText/RSpec/blob/master/RSpec.sublime-build) and paste it as `[Sublime]/Packages/User/RSpec/RSpec.sublime-build` and modify it to meet your needs.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Was also my problem. I just set the Build System to Ruby and my code works now.

Tools > Build System > Ruby